# How to force delete/unset directive from specifed element by using selector DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using library angular-inview, it is doing like jquery-inview. If any DOM element is in the current visible browser viewport, then selected directive from this element should be removed/unset.

```
<img in-view="lineInView($index, $inview, $inviewpart, $event)" />
```

JS:

```
$rootScope.lineInView = function(index, inview, inviewpart, event){
    if(inview){

      var el = angular.element(event.inViewTarget); 

      el.removeAttr('in-view');

      //$compile(el.contents())(el.scope); //doesnt work.
      return false;
    }
};
```

Any idea?

**Update 1:**

added plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9YQEXmeXQS9wLbwOiH6v?p=preview

Comment: Maybe just use `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` to add / remove your elements?

Comment: @Alrazah isnt good idea, that wil be problem with performance on mobile.

Comment: why should that be? you mean removing / adding DOM elements in general? That's not really true or at least, i never experienced it and im working at a huge cross platform mobile project atm using cordova and angularjs. dont know what i would do without ng-if actually.